# Unable to process some illegible content to be readable

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the results available in all the tables from a webpage. The content seem to be loaded dynamically but they are present in page source within id `tournament-page-data-results`. When I parse the content of that id the results look horrible. If you open the link below, you can see the table there.

[Website address](https://www.flashscore.com.au/football/china/super-league/results/)

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.flashscore.com.au/football/china/super-league/results/"

res = requests.get(url,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
item = soup.select_one("#tournament-page-data-results").text
print(item)
```

Portion of results I'm getting:

```
SA÷1¬~ZA÷CHINA: Super League¬ZEE÷nc9yRmcn¬ZB÷52¬ZY÷China¬ZC÷8v9j9Yfo¬ZD÷p¬ZE÷bDP95ewl¬ZF÷0¬ZO÷0¬ZG÷1¬ZH÷52_nc9yRmcn¬ZJ÷2¬ZL÷/football/china/super-league/¬ZX÷04China       005......0000000000183000Super League012League000¬ZCC÷0¬ZAF÷China¬~AA÷URAOleui¬AD÷1564833600¬ADE÷1564833600¬AB÷3¬CR÷3¬AC÷3¬CX÷Shanghai SIPG¬ER÷Round 21¬RW÷0¬AX÷1¬AO÷1564840697¬BX÷-1¬WQ÷¬WN÷TIA¬AF÷Tianjin Tianhai¬JB÷tpc45w7n¬WV÷tianjin-tianhai¬AS÷0¬AZ÷0¬AH÷0¬BB÷0¬BD÷0¬WM÷SHA¬AE÷Shanghai SIPG¬JA÷nNc06Jit¬WU÷shanghai-sipg¬AS÷0¬AZ÷0¬AJ÷1¬AG÷0¬BA÷0¬BC÷0¬AW÷1¬~AA÷CjtvsqMp¬AD÷1564832100¬ADE÷1564832100¬AB÷3¬CR÷3¬AC÷3¬CX÷Shandong Luneng¬ER÷Round 21¬RW÷0¬AX÷1¬AO÷1564838873¬BX÷-1¬WQ÷¬WM÷SHA¬AE÷Shandong Luneng¬JA÷QF1rHFl1¬WU÷shandong-luneng¬AG÷0¬BA÷0¬BC÷0¬WN÷GUA¬AF÷Guangzhou Evergrande¬JB÷fk6nGZ37¬WV÷guangzhou¬AS÷2¬AZ÷2¬AH÷3¬BB÷0¬BD÷3¬AW÷1¬~AA÷fBgCoPDT¬AD÷1564826400¬ADE÷1564826400¬AB÷3¬CR÷3¬AC÷3¬CX÷Tianjin Teda¬ER÷Round 21¬RW÷0¬AX÷1¬AO÷1564833359¬BX÷-1¬WQ÷¬WN÷HEN¬AF÷Henan
```

***How can I process the results to be some readable format?***

Comment: you get what you scrapped, you have to process html if you targeting table

Comment: It's a very helpful comment really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are some form of processing/formatting instruction but I am not entirely clear what. You can however use them as rules and apply via regex. Some form of key may be determinable from https://www.flashscore.com.au/x/feed/mc_10  seen in network traffic but I am simply going by repeating patterns I can see. If you convert timestamp using time zone Australia/Melbourne (AEST) you get datetime as shown on page. You can probably use the patterns as a basis to devise string replacements e.g. new line and tab and use that instead to produce the formatting.

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.flashscore.com.au/football/china/super-league/results/"
res = requests.get(url,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
item = soup.select_one("#tournament-page-data-results").text
lines = re.sub(r'¬~AA÷(.*?)¬AD÷','\n', item).split('\n')
pround = re.compile(r'¬ER÷(.*?)¬RW')
datetimestamp = re.compile(r'ADE÷(\d+)')
team1 = re.compile(r'CX÷(.*?)¬')
team2 = re.compile(r'AF÷(.*?)¬')
team1score = re.compile(r'AG÷(.*?)¬')
team2score = re.compile(r'AH÷(.*?)¬')
end_left_score = re.compile(r'BA÷(.*?)¬')
end_right_score = re.compile(r'BB÷(.*?)¬')

results = []

for line in lines[1:]:
    f_round = pround.findall(line)[0]
    unix_timestamp = datetimestamp.findall(line)[0]
    team_1 = team1.findall(line)[0]
    team_2 = team2.findall(line)[0]
    score_one = ' - '.join([team1score.findall(line)[0],team2score.findall(line)[0]])
    score_two = '('+ ' - '.join([end_left_score.findall(line)[0],end_right_score.findall(line)[0]]) + ')'

    row = [f_round, unix_timestamp, team_1, score_one, team_2,score_two]     

    results.append(row)

pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = ['Round', 'Timestamp', 'Team1','Score1','Team2','Score2'])
print(df)
```

---

**Sample rows:**

[image]

---

**Timestamp conversion:**

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
import pytz

def get_au_localtime(timestamp):
    utc_dt =  utc.localize(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp))
    au_dt = utc_dt.astimezone(au_tz)
    return au_dt.strftime(fmt)

utc = pytz.utc
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
au_tz = timezone('Australia/Sydney')
url = "https://www.flashscore.com.au/football/china/super-league/results/"
res = requests.get(url,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
item = soup.select_one("#tournament-page-data-results").text
lines = re.sub(r'¬~AA÷(.*?)¬AD÷','\n', item).split('\n')
pround = re.compile(r'¬ER÷(.*?)¬RW')
datetimestamp = re.compile(r'ADE÷(\d+)')
team1 = re.compile(r'CX÷(.*?)¬')
team2 = re.compile(r'AF÷(.*?)¬')
team1score = re.compile(r'AG÷(.*?)¬')
team2score = re.compile(r'AH÷(.*?)¬')
end_left_score = re.compile(r'BA÷(.*?)¬')
end_right_score = re.compile(r'BB÷(.*?)¬')

results = []

for line in lines[1:]:
    f_round = pround.findall(line)[0]
    date_time = get_au_localtime(int(datetimestamp.findall(line)[0]))
    team_1 = team1.findall(line)[0]
    team_2 = team2.findall(line)[0]
    score_one = ' - '.join([team1score.findall(line)[0],team2score.findall(line)[0]])
    score_two = '('+ ' - '.join([end_left_score.findall(line)[0],end_right_score.findall(line)[0]]) + ')'

    row = [f_round, date_time , team_1, score_one, team_2,score_two]     

    results.append(row)

pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = ['Round', 'Date Time', 'Team1','Score1','Team2','Score2'])
print(df)
```

---

**Timestamp conversion sample rows:**

[image]

---

**References:**

1. http://pytz.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative approach to what QHarr suggested.
As you noticed, the content of the webpage you're trying to scrape is generated dynamically. That is, the data you're interested in is "hidden" behind JavaScript objects. One way to overcome this hindrance is to resort to an automated web-browser, such as [selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/). This approach would also spare you the hassle of having to resort to regex to solve your formatting issue.
[Installing Selenium](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/#installing) is rather simple, just run `pip install -U selenium`. Most importantly, Selenium requires a driver to interface with your browser of choice. For instance, if you're using Firefox, the required driver is [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).
Here is a simple example of how you can use the combo *Selenium - BeautifulSoup* to get the information about every match listed on the webpage you provided.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox

url = 'https://www.flashscore.com.au/football/china/super-league/results/'
path_geckodriver = '<path/to/geckodriver.exe>'

browser = Firefox(executable_path=path_geckodriver)
browser.get(url)
source = browser.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
matches = soup.find_all(class_='event__match event__match--static event__match--oneLine')

for match in matches:
    print(match.get_text())
```

By calling `browser = Firefox(executable_path=path_geckodriver)` Selenium will launch Firefox. To specify which page to open, you can use `browser.get(url)`. Lastly, `browser.page_source` will get you the html of the page.
From here, you can simply rely on BeautifulSoup and use `find_all`. You just have to pass it the class identifying the div storing each match.
You should get a result that looks something like this:

```
03.08. 22:00Shanghai SIPG0 - 0Tianjin Tianhai(0 - 0)
03.08. 21:35Shandong Luneng0 - 3Guangzhou Evergrande(0 - 0)
03.08. 20:00Tianjin Teda2 - 0Henan Jianye(0 - 0)
02.08. 22:00Beijing Guoan2 - 0Hebei(0 - 0)
02.08. 22:00Guangzhou R&F2 - 2Jiangsu Suning(1 - 1)        
...
```

Comment: I use selenium at times. However, I tried to get the results using requests. Thanks for your answer @AmbaRaba.